# CSS cant stop underlining

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm having trouble with stop the underlining on my hyperlink in HTML.
I added in CSS `text-decoration:none;` but that doesnt seem to work, any suggestions?

```css
header.main h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 55px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header.main h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="main">
  <a href="./index.html">
    <h1>Test.com</h1>
    <h2>This is a test</h2>
  </a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underline came from the `<a>` tag not from th `<h2>` tag. Just add `text-decoration: none` to the `<a>` tag.

Hope this helps

```css
header.main h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 55px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

header.main h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

a {  text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<header class="main">
  <a href="./index.html">
    <h1>Test.com</h1>
    <h2>This is a test</h2>
  </a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `a` probably is your problem.

Try the following:

```
header.main a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the chrome code inspector (default key to call: `CMD+Option+i` for MacOS; `ctrl+alt+I` or `F12` for Windows and Linux), you'll see that the browser has calculated `text-decorated: none;` for `<h1>`. And the underline came from `<a>`.

To fix this use:

```
header.main a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the a tag which usually has an underline applied to it as a default in most browsers and frameworks. Simply apply `text-decoration: none;` to your a tag to solve the issue. Here is a jsfiddle with an example: **https://jsfiddle.net/dqpgacmt/**

The best way to track these kind of things down is with the developer tools in your browser. They allow you to examine the HTML markup and the CSS being applied to it.